# Bitwise operations on byte string and int

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitwise-operators, bitstring

i am in the process of converting some cython code to python, and it went well until i came to the bitwise operations. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
in_buf_word = b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00'
bits = 8
in_buf_word >>= bits
```

If i run this it will spit out this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>=: 'str' and 'int'
```

how would i fix this?

Comment: What is your expected outcome for that? Is that `8` a fixed amount, or could it be `2`, `29`, `33`, or `-1`?

Comment: bits is not a fixed amount, but in my case it is usually 8, however in_buf_word is the thing that would be sort of dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bitstring

in_buf_word = b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00'
bits = 8
in_buf_word  = bitstring.BitArray(in_buf_word ) >> bits
```

If you dont have it. Go to your terminal

```
pip3 install bitstring --> python 3
pip install bitstring --> python 2
```

To covert it back into bytes use the tobytes() method:

```
print(in_buf_word.tobytes())
```

Comment: how would i convert it back to bytes ?

Comment: @EmilBengtsson use tobytes(). see edited answer for example

Answer (score 0):

Shifting to the right by 8 bits just means cutting off the rightmost byte.

Since you already have a `bytes` object, this can be done more easily:

```
in_buf_word = in_buf_word[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by converting the bytes into an integer, shifting that, and then converting the result back into a byte string.

```
in_buf_word = b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00'
bits = 8

print(in_buf_word)  # -> b'\xff\xff\xff\xff\x00'
temp = int.from_bytes(in_buf_word, byteorder='big') >> bits
in_buf_word = temp.to_bytes(len(in_buf_word), byteorder='big')
print(in_buf_word)  # -> b'\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff'
```